# Best Camera To Purchase for my Vacation

Tags: equipment-recommendation, resolution, photography-basics

I'm going on a few vacations soon and am thinking about purchasing a new camera. Currently I just use my iPhone 6s.
I've been searching the internet endlessly it seems and have came across these few cameras. 
Just wondering which would be the best for me? I'm looking for a high resolution image, easy to use and can transfer my images to my smartphone instantly.
Nikon CoolPix B500
Canon Powershot SX730
Canon Powershot SX540

Thank you!

Comment: Can you say _why_ you want a dedicated camera as opposed to just using your phone? This information will help people to help you.

Comment: Also, why are you looking at superzoom cameras? Do you need low-light capability?

Answer (score 5):

If your goals are:

- a high resolution image,
- easy to use, and
- can transfer my images to my smartphone instantly

You should take your iPhone. It meets the first two goals just fine, and the third one *perfectly*. And as a bonus, it will cost you no additional money.

Comment: Also, double check the image quality settings on your phone to make sure they are set at the level you desire.

Comment: Yeah. There is a reason the low end market of cameras is empty - phones ate their market share.

Comment: If you're desperate to spend some serious money - upgrade to the iPhone 7 or 8 Plus, with the dual cameras.  (Or X if you really love not having a home button.)  The portrait mode is pretty good, and it's always nice to have a 35mm-ish equivalent lens available (with no digital zoom).

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with super-zoom bridge cameras.  They all use very small sensors which will provide similar iso performance to the $8 cameras used in a common smartphone.

Here's a link to dpreview's web app that allows you to compare image quality and iso performance: https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/image-comparison

How much resolution do you actually need?  What are you doing with the images?  Are you cropping heavily?

What types of photos do you want to make?  Depending upon your answer to this important question, you may need something entirely different that the models that you've listed.